# iOS 7 Background Fetch: Large Import Operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, grand-central-dispatch

I would like to do a large background fetch and Core Data import which takes between 10 and 50 minutes.

Would that be possible with the background fetch method in iOS 7?

The Apple Docs states that a background fetch should take less than 30 seconds otherwise it will be *called less often*.

However, if I am ok with my background fetch being called "less often" is there a limitation on what can be done in a background fetch (e.g. Core Data writes) and how long it may take?

Comment: I think Apple's position is that background fetch mode is for fetching. If you can squeeze in processing (ie, insertion into Core Data in your case) then good for you but that isn't really what the mode is for. So in your case you're probably supposed to write the data to disk unparsed and parse it only if the application is launched via the ordinary channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the watch dog will eventually kill your application.  The length of time that your application gets to run is dependent on the needs of the system and can vary by a large amount.

If you have an import that takes that long then I would suggest designing it so that it can be interruptible and resumable.  Otherwise it will never complete.